# Installing QGIS on Mac OS

Tags: qgis, installation, macos

I have installed Python 3.6.8 and am attempting to run QGIS 3.14 on Mac OS 10.15.5. I get this message, which doesn't show in any existing questions I could find:
[image: Apple cannot check for malicious software]

Should I try an earlier version of QGIS?

Tried 3.10 and got same response.

Comment: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34018#issuecomment-578186707

Answer (score 2):

From: https://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis/ There a simple way to force it to install – right-click the installer file and select Open, this will trigger an extra option in the security warning to install it anyways. Works on an already installed app as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you get a malicious software won't install warning for any of these, go to the Apple menu > System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General Tab > Allow Anyway

This will let you install the software.

Comment: it worked for me! thank you!