# QGIS software does not install on MAC

Tags: qgis, installation, mac

MAC is telling me that it cannot verify software for malware and stops installation.

Any hint?

Comment: can you put some more info? like - Version of QGIS you downloaded, OS version, when during installation the message pops up...... you might get a better response to your question :)

Comment: By the way: this problem seems to be a known issue that is easy to resolve (see my answer). However, when asking a question here, always include details - in your case here OP version and software version you want to install, error messages (as text, not as screenshot); and generally: what you've tried, where you're stuck and (often useful) a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem for Mac. Either Presst `Ctrl` key and double click to open the downloaded installation file or right-click on it/open: then you get the option to open without checking for malicious software.

See: https://youtu.be/6YDWNx8sJQw?t=114 and [Installing QGIS 3.14 on Mac OS 10.15.5](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366339/installing-qgis-3-14-on-mac-os-10-15-5)