# QGIS won't run on MacBook Pro

Tags: qgis, installation, mac

I have recently downloaded version 3.26.0 and when I try and run it I get this message:

> “QGIS” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious
> software. This software needs to be updated. Contact the developer for
> more information.
>
> Chrome downloaded this file on 8 July 2022 from qgis.org.

Is this due to restrictions in place on my work computer or is this something I can fix myself with a little help from one of the developers?

Comment: Same question was answered here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366339/installing-qgis-3-14-on-mac-os-10-15-5 see also here: https://youtu.be/6YDWNx8sJQw?t=110

Answer (score 1):

Below is a screenshot of the error you may encountered. This one occur because QGIS is not yet notarized as required by macOS Catalina (10.15) security rules (as per the official [documentation](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html)).

[image]

The [Apple support](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/apple-cant-check-app-for-malicious-software-mchleab3a043/mac) suggest to :

1. Locate the QGIS installer in the Finder (don’t use Launchpad to locate the app.)
2. Control-click the app icon, then choose Open from the shortcut menu
3. Click Open

If the error persists, go to System Preferences and choose Security & Privacy and do this (as per the image below) :

[image]

**Note** : Since you have a work computer, I'm not sure you'll be able to apply any of these procedures. But you can try anyway !