# My computer will not download QGIS

Tags: qgis

I downloaded QGIS from QGIS.org, version 3.28.2. My computer says it wont open it because Apple cannot check it for malicious software. I dont know what to do. [image: can't be opened]

Comment: This question has been asked before and there is a solution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/366434/88814 See also https://youtu.be/6YDWNx8sJQw at 1:50

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to be something that myself and collegues with M2 chips had aswell,

You need to go into Apple menu > System Settings, then click Privacy & Security  in the sidebar find the app within there and click on it then open.